# Clickable links in Shiny Datatable

Tags: r, datatables, shiny

I created a table containing some HTML links using Shiny's renderDataTable. The links are not clickable, though, instead they render literally:

https://samizdat.shinyapps.io/zakazky/

Do you have any idea what could be wrong? It worked fine before upgrading Shiny to the version 0.11... Thanks!

Comment: include your tried code

Comment: As I read the code that gets pushed to my browser this line is doing the display of the area that I think you are having difficulty with, which suggests to me that we really do need to know what is in that underlying table: ` <div id="filtrovanaTabulka" class="shiny-datatable-output"></div>`

Comment: Thanks, I have found the solution. The renderDataTable function in Shiny has an argument escape. It was most likey set to TRUE by default in the new version. When I change it, it works again. More info: http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/renderDataTable.html

Comment: You should put 'setting the escape argument to FALSE' as an answer. This was quite helpful - thanks!

Answer (score 54):

I had the same problem. The `escape = FALSE` option for renderDataTable solved it, as you mentioned in the comments.

Here is complete code for an app with a table that has links.

If you are doing this, you will want each link to be unique based on a value in the table. I move this code into a function so its cleaner.

```
#app.R#

library(shiny)

createLink <- function(val) {
  sprintf('<a href="https://www.google.com/#q=%s" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Info</a>',val)
}

ui <- fluidPage(  
  titlePanel("Table with Links!"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h4("Click the link in the table to see
         a google search for the car.")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput('table1')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({

    my_table <- cbind(rownames(mtcars), mtcars)
    colnames(my_table)[1] <- 'car'
    my_table$link <- createLink(my_table$car)
    return(my_table)

  }, escape = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: A further note for whoever ends up here debugging: if 'my_table' in this example is a datatable object, you need to make sure it has escape=FALSE option as well (only setting it for renderDataTable wont work). then a simple fix would be my_table<-datatable(my_table, escape=F)

Answer (score 1):

Note: Not allowed to add a comment on williamsurles reply because "insufficient reputation" .

williamsurles answer introduces security vulnerabilities: [Html and javascript injections (aka XSS = cross site scripting vulnerability)](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/). You should be really careful when you deactivate escaping. If any column of the table contains `"` the html code will be improperly rendered. And, if an attacker properly craft the content of the rendered table, it will be able to execute code in your browser.

`val` should be properly escaped in `createLink` `sprintf`. And, `escape = ...` should  escape everything but the `link` column as specified in the documentation:

> escape: Whether to escape HTML entities in the table: ‘TRUE’ means to
> escape the whole table, and ‘FALSE’ means not to escape it.
> Alternatively, you can specify numeric column indices or
> column names to indicate which columns to escape, e.g. ‘1:5’
> (the first 5 columns), ‘c(1, 3, 4)’, or ‘c(-1, -3)’ (all
> columns except the first and third), or ‘c('Species',
> 'Sepal.Length')’.

EDIT: Here is with proper escaping:

```
library(shiny)

df <- data.frame(name = c(
                     'quotes like that"',
                     "injection",
                     "stdtext"),
                 text = c(
                     'Text with "word" in quotes', ## Some quotes
                     '"><script>alert(1);</script><"', ## dangerous column, potentially injected by an attacker
                     "Plop"))

ui <- fluidPage(  
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput('table')
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table <- renderDataTable({

      my_table <- df
      my_table$link <- sapply(my_table$name,
                              function (n)
                              {
                                  ## tags$a function produces adequately escaped links
                                  as.character(tags$a(n, href=paste0("https://www.google.com/#q=", n)))
                              })
      return(my_table)

     ## only deactivate escaping for `link` column
  }, escape = c(-3))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35596584)

Comment: That's why it should have been better to be a comment: it fix a big issue in the current answer. What should I have done? Copy the whole wrong code and fix it?

Comment: I added full code, in addition to my explanation. Do we really want code containing flagrant known security vulnerabilities shared on stackoverflow without any warning?