# URLdecode unsuccessfully creating link

Tags: html, r, shiny

I have a website URL that I am trying to turn into a hyperlink using R that displays the first 25 characters for a shiny page.  The code that use to do that is below.

```
val <- "https://www.google.com/"
sprintf(paste0('<a href="', URLdecode(val),'" target="_blank">', substr(val, 1, 25) ,'</a>'))
```

If `val` is set equal to the login page for National Instruments where on my chrome browser the information is autofilling for a saved username and password based on one of my past logins that I saved:

```
val <- "https://lumen.ni.com/nicif/us/LMS_LOGIN/content.xhtml?du=http%3A%2F%2Fsine.ni.com%3A80%2Fmyni%2Fself-paced-training%2Fapp%2Fmain.xhtml%3Fsessionid%3D3-E63B1535-F81F-46C9-A867-E3176E756971%26requestedurl%3Dlearncenter%252Easp%253Fid%253D178409%2526page%253D1"
```

the sprintf function throws the error `Error in sprintf(paste0("<a href=\"", URLdecode(val), "\" target=\"_blank\">",  : too few arguments`

The issue appears to be towards the end.  If the link is truncated before the `%252Easp`, the sprintf function works as intended.  This is the first I have worked with html, so as far as my initial research goes, the R function `URLdecode` should take care of special characters to ensure that this doesn't happen.  If someone could explain to me why this is throwing the error it is and how to fix it I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Why are you using `sprintf` here? You seem to just be pasting values together? The "%" characters mean something special to `sprintf` but you don't seem to be using it that way.

Comment: Originally I was mimicing the structure of the answer found at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117556/clickable-links-in-shiny-datatable

Comment: That doesn't seem to be relevant to what you need to do. Just remove the `sprintf` and keep the `paste0()` and I think that will do what you want.

Comment: perfect, I just tried it out and you are correct, that fixes my issue.